# Create S3 bucket policy for ssm resource data sync that allows new accounts added access without manually adding a statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, organization, aws-ssm

I am attempting to deploy a SSM Inventory Collection and a Resource Data Sync via Cloudformation in 15 accounts. I am able to manually add each account by adding a statement in the central s3 bucket for proper access. I was wondering is there a way to create a policy that allows newly created AWS accounts in the future to have proper access without adding a statement to the s3 bucket policy. Below is the documentation I have followed. I was using this method to add each account below

```
"Resource": [
     "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*/accountid=123456789012/*", 
     "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*/accountid=444455556666/*",
     "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*/accountid=777788889999/*"
                ],
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-inventory-datasync.html
Further in the documentation, I see you can create a resource data sync for accounts defined in AWS Organizations. But this still doesnt accomplish granting any new accounts where template gets deployed, access will be granted.

Creating an inventory resource data sync for accounts defined in AWS Organizations

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "SSMBucketPermissionsCheck",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ssm.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::S3_bucket_name"
    },
    {
      "Sid": " SSMBucketDelivery",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ssm.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/bucket-prefix/*/accountid=*/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control",
          "s3:RequestObjectTag/OrgId": "organization-id",
          "aws:SourceAccount": "123456789012"
        },
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:ssm:*:123456789012:resource-data-sync/*"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": " SSMBucketDeliveryTagging",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ssm.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObjectTagging",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/bucket-prefix/*/accountid=*/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have played around with a few policies but doesn't seem to work

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::inventorycollectionsync/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-mb7bem0c79"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Error in the below template I replaced Put with Get

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SSMBucketPermissionsCheck",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ssm.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
        },
        {
            "Sid": " SSMBucketOrgDelivery",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ssm.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*/accountid=*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": " SSMBucketDelivery",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ssm.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*/accountid=*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:RequestObjectTag/OrgId": "org-id",
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": " SSMBucketDeliveryTagging",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ssm.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObjectTagging",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*/accountid=*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```